# Output a variable in Twig BEFORE translation?

Tags: internationalization, twig, gettext, twig-extension, php-gettext

I'm using the Slim PHP micro framework with Twig and the translation extension i18n.

I have a need to output translated country names, and would prefer to do it using the translation extension rather than building an array and fetching the name manually in PHP.

So I tried this in my Twig template:

```
{% set country="trans-country-name("~isoCountryCode~")" %}
{% trans %}
    This is a list of all the numbers in {{country}}.    
{% endtrans %}
```

and this in my `.po` file:

```
msgid "This is a list of all the numbers in %country%."
msgstr "Detta är en lista över samtliga nummer i %country%."

msgid "trans-country-name(NO)"
msgstr "Norge"
```

I was hoping that this would result in

```
"Detta är en lista över samtliga nummer i Norge."
```

but instead I just get

```
"Detta är en lista över samtliga nummer i trans-country-name(NO)."
```

Is it possible to have the translation extension parse `trans-country-name(NO)` as text to be translated?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was going about it sort of backwards. The solution seems obvious in hindsight - simply use the `| trans` filter on the `country` variable first, and then just use that straight in the text to be translated.

Twig template:

```
{% set country = ("trans-country-name("~numbers[0].countryNames.code~")") | trans %}
{% trans %}This is a list of all the numbers in {{country}}.{% endtrans %}
```

`.po` file

```
msgid "This is a list of all the numbers in %country%."
msgstr "Detta är en lista över samtliga telefonnummer i %country%."

msgid "trans-country-name(NO)"
msgstr "Norge"
```

My final solution was to scrap the country code in favour of simply using the country names directly instead:

```
{% set country=numbers[0].countryNames.displayName | trans %}
{% trans %}This is a list of all the numbers in {{country}}.{% endtrans %}
```

```
msgid "This is a list of all the numbers in %country%."
msgstr "Detta är en lista över samtliga telefonnummer i %country%."

msgid "Norway"
msgstr "Norge"
```